# Passing nested inline styles to ant design components

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am trying to style a default ant design Radio Button component and need to use inline styles since I am obtaining the styles dynamically from JS variables. However, I can't seem to use nesting inside the 'style' prop passed to target descendant components.

This is how it looks now:
[image: This is how it looks]

This is how I want it to look :
[image: This is how I want it to look]

Basically I need a way to use the nested selectors here :

```
#ripeness .ant-radio-checked .ant-radio-inner {
    background-color: red;
    border-color: red;
}
```

In this code:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To override antd styles you can do in two different ways:

First: you can assign classes to your components and then use CSS to override these styles:
OBS_1: you can also override antd default classes with CSS
OBS_2: in this case you must use `!important` after every prop you chance so antd will not override this style

```
// globals.css

// to override default antd classes add this instead:
// .ant-radio-inner or .ant-radio-checked or any other class you want
.my-radio-button {
  background-color: red !important;
}

// root_component.tsx
import 'path/to/globals.css'

// component.tsx
...

// if you overrided only antd default classes you doesn't need to add `className` prop
<Radio className='my-radio-button'>test</Radio>
```

Seccond way is to use a JS/TS file and import it inside your component:

```
// styles.ts - if you use JS remove types declaration
import { CSSProperties } from 'react'
import { theme as antdTheme } from 'antd'

type StylesType = {
  // if function: Radio: (enabled: boolean) => CSSProperties
  Radio: CSSProperties
}

/**
 * Styles
 *
 * @return {StylesType} styles
 */
function Styles(): StylesType {
  const { useToken } = antdTheme
  const { token: theme } = useToken()

  // this also can be a function
  // e.g.: function Radio(enabled: boolean):CSSProperties {
  //   return {
  //     color: enabled? 'red' : 'blue'
  //   } 
  // }
  const Radio: CSSProperties = {
    color: 'red',
    anyOtherProp: theme.colorPrimary
  }

  return {
    Radio
  }
}

export default Styles


// component.tsx
import Styles from 'path/to/styles'

....


const S = Styles()

return (

  // if function: 
  // <Radio 
  //   styles={ S.Radio( propToHandleRadioEnabled ) }
  // >test</Radio>
  <Radio styles={S.Radio}>test</Radio>
)
```

Both ways work well but sometimes you'll still need to add CSS to change some styles.

In your case, as you need different colors for each radio I would suggest you to use seccond way as you can have a function and use it to pass desired color as function param.

Hope this helps you :D

Comment: but it does not show that way you target .ant-radio-checked .