# How to change antd's overlayClassName with styled components?

Tags: antd, styled-components

I have a SC dropdown component

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Dropdown as AntDropdown } from "antd";

const Dropdown = styled(AntDropdown).attrs({
    overlayClassName: "ant-override"
})`
  .ant-override {
    .ant-dropdown-menu {
      background: #333333;
      min-width: 230px;

      box-shadow: 0 1.55px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
      border-radius: 16px;
    }
    .ant-dropdown-menu-item:hover {
      background: #262626;
      color: red;
    }
  }
`
```

Also I have a dropdown component

```
import { FC } from "react"
import { DropdownProps } from "antd/lib/dropdown/dropdown";
import { DropdownStyles } from "./styles";

const { Dropdown } = DropdownStyles

export const DropdownMenu: FC<DropdownProps> = ({overlayClassName, ...rest}) => <Dropdown overlayClassName={"ant-override"} {...rest} />;
```

The problem is that I don't understand why Dropdown can't see ant-override class. Override isn't working

Comment: I don't know if there is a reason you're using styled components with antd but in my projects I'm using JS/TS files to style my antd components and sometimes use CSS to override some default paddings and sizes. Take a look in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76905598/9894625) example and see if it's better to you

Answer (score 0):

Either import a separate css file. Add this to your css file and import it in that component and you should be able to see an immediate effect:

```
.ant-dropdown .ant-dropdown-menu{
  background: #333333;
  min-width: 230px;

  box-shadow: 0 1.55px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
  border-radius: 16px;
}
```

Or consider using a custom dropdown using `dropdownRender` and wrap the menu in a styled component like so:

```
const StyledDropDown = styled.div`
  .ant-dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #D1DAEA !important;
    color: red;
  }
`

return <Dropdown menu={{ items }} dropdownRender={(menu) => {
  return <StyledDropDown>{menu}</StyledDropDown>
}}>
</Dropdown>
```